# Show that $\sigma(n)$ is equally often even and odd

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function, parity

Let $\sigma(n)$ be the divisor sum of $n$: 
$$ \sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n} d. $$
I was interested in the parity of $\sigma(n)$ and tried to check whether $\sigma(n)$ is unexpected often even for odd $n$ and vice versa. No result.

> Thus I conjectured that
>   $$ \lim_{x\longrightarrow\infty} \dfrac{|\{1:n\leq x,~ Parity(n) \not = Parity(\sigma(n)) \}|}{|\{1:n\leq x, ~Parity(n) = Parity(\sigma(n)) \}|} = 1.$$

I checked this fraction for $x$ up to $100000$ and the conjecture seems to be true. Here are some values:

```
x        Fraction
---      ---
10,000   1.02799
50,000   1.01264
100,000  1.00898
```

However I am not able to prove it. **Can you prove that $\sigma(n)$ does not prefer any parity?**

Comment: I would look at the formula for the sigma function (as referred by @FabianSchn ). It shouldn't be too hard from there.

Comment: @marlasca23 Thanks, can you please elaborate how you would proceed? Of course I dont know any reason why $\sigma(n)$ should prefer some parity but how to prove it...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sigma(n)$ is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) such that 
$$ \sigma(p^k) = 1+p+\ldots+p^k = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1} $$
for any prime $p$ and any $k\geq 1$. If $p=2$ we have that $\sigma(p^k)$ is certainly odd, while if $p>2$ the parity of $\sigma(p^k)$ only depends on the parity of $k$. In particular $\sigma(n)$ is odd iff $n$ is a number of the form $2^k(2m+1)^2$. The set of these numbers has [asymptotic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) zero (since in the interval $[1,M]$ there are less than $3\sqrt{M}$ numbers of this kind), hence the parity of $n$ and the parity of $\sigma(n)$ are essentially unrelated (loosely speaking, $\sigma(n)$ *is almost surely even*), as stated by your claim.

Comment: Thanks, great answer.

Comment: @FabianSchn. Now $f(n) = (-1)^{1+\sum_{p^k \| n} \sigma(p^k)}$ is more interesting. It is multiplicative and equally distributed. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s} = \frac{(1-2^{1-s})(1+2^{-s})}{1-2^{-s}}\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}$ which is analytic for $\Re(s) \ge 1$ so that (with the same method as for the prime number theorem) $\sum_{n \le x} f(n) = o(x)$. The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to $\sum_{n \le x} f(n) = O(\sqrt{x}\log^2 x)$